having a new environment share the same counter with a theorem environment without copying the italicization
I'm writing some notes and to make things easy to reference clearly, I'm adopting the convention of having my theorems, corollarys, definitions, etc. all share the same counter.
% environments
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

But a problem with this is that my Examples and Remarks are all italicized (just like the theorem environment), which I don't like.  Is there a straight-forward way to change this?

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us if you use a package such as amsthm or ntheorem to help create theorem-like environments.

I'm using amsmath and amssymb but not amsthm.

@Mico Not sure if that addresses the unified counter requirement or not?

I think it will be harder than I thought to get the behaviour I really want, but I agree with @Mico that the referenced question is similar to this one.  Thank you!

@cfr - Going by the OP's code snippet, it looks like they have already solved the unified-counter issue on their own. I'll post a sample answer to make sure both of the OP's objectives are dealt with.

I suggest that you start loading amsthm in addition to amsmath and amssymb. That way, you'll have access to pre-defined theorem styles called definition and remark, in addition to the default theorem theorem style.
It looks to me like you've already solved the unified-counter issue.

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{amsthm}
%\theoremstyle{theorem} % 'theorem' is the default style
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition} % header: bold; body: upright non-bold
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{remark} % header: italic non-bold; body: upright non-bold
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example
\setcounter{subsection}{3}

\begin{theorem} Hello, World.    \end{theorem}
\begin{corollary} Hello, World.  \end{corollary}
\begin{lemma} Hello, World.      \end{lemma}
\begin{definition} Hello, World. \end{definition}
\begin{example} Hello, World.    \end{example}
\begin{remark} Hello, World.     \end{remark}

\end{document}


Thanks .......!

This specifically addresses an issue that I had but failed to vocalize, namely to keep the bold headings while getting rid of the italicized statements, as you did with Definition and Example.  Thank you!

For anyone looking to customize further, see @percusse's answer here
